# Unexpected behavior of java.concurrent.Semaphore

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

I am in a situation where I need to use Semaphore from the java.concurrent package so that I may be able to restrict the number of threads taking hold of a certain resource. Following is the very basic setup (code):

```
    package semaphor;

    import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

    /**
     * Created by NawazishMohammad on 15-04-2015.
     */
    public class SemaphoreTester {
       public static void main (String [] args){
           new Thread(new MyRunnable(), "T1").start();
           new Thread(new MyRunnable(), "T2").start();
           new Thread(new MyRunnable(), "T3").start();
           new Thread(new MyRunnable(), "T4").start();
       }
    }

    class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            semaphoreStatus();
        }

        public void semaphoreStatus(){
            System.out.println("Thread waiting for permit: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(2);
            try {
                sem.acquire();
                System.out.println("Thread got permit: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                System.out.println("Thread releasing permit: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                sem.release();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

}
```

I am getting the following output

```
Thread waiting for permit: T1
Thread waiting for permit: T2
Thread waiting for permit: T3
Thread waiting for permit: T4
Thread got permit: T3
Thread got permit: T4
Thread got permit: T2
Thread got permit: T1
Thread releasing permit: T2
Thread releasing permit: T4
Thread releasing permit: T3
Thread releasing permit: T1
```

Note that although I have instantiated Semaphore for total concurrent thread count of two "`new Semaphore(2);`", implying that at a time only 2 threads can have access to a particular resource, I can find all 4 threads: T1-T4  having acquired Semaphore permit (and hence access to the restricted resource). Could anyone please clarify my misunderstanding, if any, about `java.concurrent.Semaphore` since I do not expect the output:

```
Thread got permit: T3
Thread got permit: T4
Thread got permit: T2
Thread got permit: T1
```

I understand that Semaphore, at any instance, cannot tender more than "2" permits (for this example) to any number of threads that might be waiting.

Comment: Did the below answer assist with this problem, Nawazish?

Comment: Great, would you accept it, then? To accept an answer, find the tick mark to the left of it, and click it so it turns green. In doing so, this marks the question as resolved and rewards the helper with a few unicorn points as a thank-you for their work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating a new semaphore in each thread, meaning that each thread will see a different Semaphore. Instead of calling `Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(2);` inside `semaphoreStatus()`, you should construct the Semaphore outside of the threads and then share it with them.

Comment: Almost identical wording, got me 45 seconds earlier.